# How should I move my completed Django Project in a Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I started learning django a few days back and started a project, by luck the project made is good and I'm thinking to deploy it. However I didn't initiate it in virtual environment. have made a virtual environment now and want to move project to that. I want to know how can I do that ? I have created requirements.txt whoever it has included all the irrelevant library names. How can I get rid of them and have only that are required for the project.

Comment: Presumably you know which libraries your project is using, because you have made use of them in your code. So make a new requirements file based on those dependencies.

Comment: @solarissmoke Got it, Do I have to move my existing code under virtual environment directory ?, Sir.

Comment: No, your own code should not be in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is completely unrelated to the environment you run it on.

The environment represents which python version are you using (2,3...) and the libraries installed.

To answer your question, the only thing you need to do is run your `manage.py` commands from the python executable in the new virtual environment. Of course install all of the necessary libraries in the new environment if you haven't already did so.

It might be a problem if you created a python3 environment while the one you created was in python2, but at that point it's a code portability issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Last thing I wanted to know if I can deploy my project without actual virtual env ? Like the stage it's into now, can I deploy the project if I haven't initiated virtual env ? Will I face any problem ?

Comment: There are two ways you could run your project:
From the installed python executable
From a portable virtual environment, it is impossible to run it otherwise, the venv is the most common, easy and portable solution. You can deploy the project without it but it will not run by itself.